# Non-invertible operators

Tags: mathematical-physics

1. Can the matrix representation of some linear operators on some vector space be singular?

Comment: Certainly - both questions could be answered in a purely mathematical context.

Comment: You should **really** split this question up into two. The first question is not quite clear: are you asking "are there linear operators on some vector space whose matrix representation is singular?"? If so, you should make it that precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can singular matrices (with determinant=0) represent linear operators in a vector space?

Yes. The definition of a [linear operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearOperator.html) includes no restrictions on invertibility.

> Is the cardinality of two segments of different length of the real line is same or different?

It is the same, namely $|[a,b]|=|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ for any $a\neq b\in\mathbb{R}$.